# Is there a way to convert a literal object in a string to an object?

Tags: javascript

If I have this string:

```
{some_name:{other_name:"text",array:["first","second",3]}}
```

Is there a way to turn it into a usable object in JavaScript?

JSON.parse() can't do it because it expects the attributes to be surrounded in quotes like this

```
{"some_name":{"other_name":"text","array":["first","second"]}}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this string from?

Comment: @kellys I was working with minecraft commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```js
eval('foo = {some_name:{other_name:"text",array:["first","second",3]}}');

console.log(foo);
```

`foo` will be the usable object.

(but don't do it, eval is evil)

---

Cleaner way

You can transform it to a valid JSON and parse it.

```js
const bar = '{some_name:{other_name:"text",array:["first","second",3]}}';
const foo = JSON.parse(bar.replace(/([^"])(\w+):/g, '$1"$2":'))

console.log(foo);
```